# What's wrong with this number extracting Regex?

Tags: regex

I have a string like the following:

```
<br><b>224h / 15.45 verbuchte Stunden</b>
```

I want to extract the numbers and have created the following Regex:

```
([0-9]\.?[0-9]{0,2})h\s\/\s([0-9]\.?[0-9]{0,2})
```

But for the preceding string this gives me the numbers 224 and 15 instead of 15.45.
What's wrong with this Regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you allow only one digit before the dot.

Try this, I used `{1,2}` as quantifier before the dot, change it to your needs. Probably `+` would be a better choice, it allows one or more.

```
([0-9]\.?[0-9]{0,2})h\s\/\s([0-9]{1,2}\.?[0-9]{0,2})
```

A better regex could be this

```
([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?)h\s*\/\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?)
```

I made here the complete fraction part optional and require at least one and at most 2 digits after the dot and minimum one before.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer is given by stema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10010345/256544).

If your regex engine supports character classes it could be a little bit more compact like this:

```
(\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,2})h\s/\s(\d{1,2}\.?\d{0,2})
```

`\d` is a [shorthand character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand) for `[0-9]`